# making column vector from the rows of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 12 columns and Five Rows. I need to convert this into a column vector with each row being successively pasted one below other.

**For example** 
`1 2 3 A a b c B d e f C g h i` I need the final output as `A1 a b c d e f g h i`

Comment: please include the example in your original post and not in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can transpose the dataset, concatenate it to a `vector` and create a single column data.frame

```
out <- data.frame(col1 = c(t(df1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rownames to be which column it comes from try,

```
data.frame(all = unlist(mtcars))
#                   all
# mpg1           21.000
# mpg2           21.000
# mpg3           22.800
# mpg4           21.400
# mpg5           18.700
# mpg6           18.100
```